# Loop Variable in GOTO iMacros

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

I'm trying to make a loop in iMacros that enters into a single guitar page, then waits 1 second, and repeats itself for products 152429 to 150590:

```
var MACRO = "CODE:SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";  
MACRO += "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
MACRO += "URL GOTO=http://localhost/guitar-sale-sample" + "\n";
MACRO += "URL GOTO=javascript:gotoProductPage({{i}},'1')" + "\n";
MACRO += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";

for ( i=152429; i<150590; i-- )
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);    
iimPlay(MACRO);
}
```

To access each guitar product page, I launch the gotoProductPage function, which needs the number of the product. I'm putting it through the i, but apparently it doesn't recognize the i variable.

PD: I am using Firefox 5.0, so I can use the navigation bar to launch the function (it works if I introduce manually a number, like javascript:gotoProductPage(150200,'1'), also from the javascript console, it works fine declaring the variable in javascript and putting it inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working!!

```
TAB T=1

SET !LOOP 0
SET !VAR1 152429
ADD !VAR1 -{{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO=javascript:gotoProductPage({{!VAR1}},'1')
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=http://localhost/guitar-sale-sample
```

Above "Play (Loop)" in the Firefox extension, I defined the Max to 2000, so each time it loops its keeps on substracting x+1 to !VAR1, looping through the 2000 products.